# Why does d3.js not consider my <tr> and <td> elements?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to develop a better understanding of how selections work in d3.js.
When I am selecting h2 elements they become part of the selection, just as expected. However if try to select tr elements, I end up with an empty selection.

```
var selectionOne =  d3.selectAll('h2');
var selectionTwo = d3.selectAll('tr');

console.log(selectionOne);
console.log(selectionTwo);
```

I have prepared a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/386er/9L3uqzL5/2/) Ideas, anyone ?

Comment: Do you have tables in the first place? You can't have a tr or td without a table to put them in.

Comment: Yes, that worked ! Thanks alot !